# What can I use as Replacement for ResultSetFuture in Cassandra 4.x?

Tags: cassandra, completable-future, datastax-java-driver, completion-stage

I have to upgrade Cassandra  to 4.x.
This was the code previously written in cassandra 3.5

```
 protected <T> Stream<T> getAll(Stream<Statement> statements, Mapper<T> mapper) {
        List<ResultSetFuture> futures = statements
                .peek(p -> cassandraReads.inc())
                .map(s -> session.session().executeAsync(s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return futures.stream()
                .map(ResultSetFuture::getUninterruptibly)
                .map(mapper::map)
                .flatMap(r -> StreamSupport.stream(r.spliterator(), false));
    }
```

I have done some changes...

```
 List<CompletionStage<AsyncResultSet>> futures = statements
                .peek(p -> cassandraReads.inc())
                .map(s -> session.getSession().executeAsync(s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

BUT what should I use in place of `.map(ResultSetFuture::getUninterruptibly)` since it has been removed now.
Since I am new to Cassandra and asynchronous programming any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already mixing async and blocking calls in your code, I'd suggest that you go fully blocking and use `Session.execute` instead of `Session.executeAsync`. It's going to make things much easier. Then you could rewrite your code as follows:

```
protected <T> Stream<T> getAll(Stream<Statement<?>> statements, Mapper<T> mapper) {
  return statements
      .peek(p -> cassandraReads.inc())
      .map(s -> session.execute(s))
      .flatMap(rs -> StreamSupport.stream(rs.spliterator(), false))
      .map(mapper::map);
}
```

Note: I'm changing slightly your `Mapper` interface, which I assume would be:

```
public interface Mapper<T> {
  T map(Row row);
}
```

(You could actually replace this `Mapper` interface with just `Function<Row, T>` btw.)

Other than that, as Erick Ramirez said, please have a look at [this page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/core/async/) to understand how to write proper async code with driver 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

The API for asynchronous programming isn't actually determined by the version of the Cassandra cluster you're connecting to. What matters is the version of the Java driver you're using.

If you're still using Java driver 3.x, your code should continue to work for the most part until Java driver 3.11. See [Asynchronous programming in Java driver 3.11](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/async/).

It isn't until you upgrade to the Java driver 4.x that you will run into breaking changes since v4.x is not binary-compatible with earlier versions of the Java driver (see [Upgrade guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/upgrade_guide/) for details).

If you do upgrade to the Java driver 4.x, you can find [working examples for asynchronous programming here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/core/async/). Cheers!